# Custom field with special constrains in DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add a custom field with some special constrains in DRF serializer. Following are 2 sample models:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
class ModelB(models.Model):
    field4 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field5 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What I want is a serializer based on ModelA, but with a custom field displaying a string combining field5s of all ModelB instances this ModelA instance has.

I know this API design is a little bit weird, but based on the existing code base, we have to do it this way.

Also I wanna this field to be writable, so SerializerMethodField doesn't work. I tried to follow the example [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples).

But my case is a little bit different, since it involves multiple models. Some sample code would be very helpful! Thx!

Comment: You should use the `to_representation()` method. Like this you can do what you want.